# Oil sanctions "made the crisis in Venezuela worse for ordinary people, its existence is now its justification (and is) very hard to remove." Why so?

Tags: united-states, sanctions, venezuela

The NPR podcast and transcript [As the price of gas goes up, can the U.S. turn to Venezuela for oil?](https://www.npr.org/2022/04/01/1090192912/as-the-price-of-gas-goes-up-can-the-u-s-turn-to-venezuela-for-oil) features [journalist](https://www.nytimes.com/by/william-neuman) and former New York Times Andes region bureau chief, and author of the book [Things Are Never So Bad That They Can't Get Worse; Inside the Collapse of Venezuela](https://us.macmillan.com/books/9781250266163/thingsareneversobadthattheycantgetworse) (NYTimes [review](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/15/books/review/things-are-never-so-bad-that-they-cant-get-worse-venezuela-william-neuman.html)) William Neuman saying the following about US sanctions against Venezuela, with the context of the US president Joe Biden's goal of making more oil available globally to replace/offset Russian oil exports:

> **MARTINEZ:** But if that continues to happen, though, William, if the price of oil keeps going up and up and up to a point where **Biden would have to maybe make strange bedfellows with Venezuela**, I mean, could he maybe leverage the U.S. market in exchange for democratic reforms in Venezuela, or do something where it would help the people of Venezuela actually get something good out of this deal?
>
> **NEUMAN:** Sure. Well, you know, the U.S. policy, even at the end of the Trump administration, was to promote negotiation between the opposition in Venezuela and Maduro. And one of the things that they discussed when the Biden folks went to talk to Maduro was resuming negotiations. And that's still being talked about in Venezuela. But in terms of - what everybody's hoping for is some kind of negotiation that would guarantee a more fair election. There's a presidential election coming up in 2024. And the country's politics are all pointed to that. **The problem is, with the sanctions, once you put them in - it's very easy to put sanctions on. It's very difficult to remove them. So you have this oil sanction. And even though it hasn't given you the results that you wanted and it's actually made the crisis in Venezuela worse for ordinary people, its existence is now it's justification. So once it's there, it's very hard to remove the thing.** So there's incentive for Maduro to try and do something. There's incentive for the U.S. The question is, what sort of political arrangement can you get in Venezuela?**
>
> **MARTINEZ:** But if the U.S., William, were to somehow start doing business with Venezuela, allow American oil companies to operate more in Venezuela, would that legitimize the presidency of Nicolas Maduro?
>
> **NEUMAN:** I don't think that it legitimizes Maduro. You know, I was talking the other day to Chuo Torrealba, who's an activist in Caracas. And he was the head of the coalition of opposition political parties for several years. And he would - talking about the sanctions, he calls it the politics of pain. There's this very cynical logic behind the sanctions, which is that if we make things bad enough, if we squeeze the economy and squeeze people and increase their suffering, then the people will rise up and rebel against the government. Or the armed forces will stage a coup to get rid of Maduro. But it doesn't work that way. People who are starving don't make revolutions. It hasn't worked that way in Venezuela. And Chuo, who I was talking with, he says, to make politics with people's pain is a mistake.

**Question:** According to Neuman, even though oil sanctions have "made the crisis in Venezuela worse for ordinary people, its existence is now its justification (and it is therefore) very hard to remove." Is it possible to find either from Neuman's extensive writings on the subject or from a better understanding than mine of how US sanctions work the following:

1. The existence of oil sanctions on Venezuela have become its justification.
2. They are therefore very hard to remove.

While these are stated in the the quoted short interview, their underlying veracity or justification are not clear to me from it.

Comment: Have you tried reading his book or watching his talks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSDccEYIcM8 ?

Comment: It might take some guesswork to answer your Q because e.g. he talks how Venezuelans are now happy eating lentils instead of burgers. So I guess he means to say there was adaptation on both sides, but I'm not sure if that's what he means there by "its existence is now it's justification".

Comment: The other thing might be some Cuba analogy where the sanctions were kept in place a long time in no small part because of the diaspora, and there's now some of that too when it comes to Venezuela, but I've not seen him explicitly making that point, although I don't have the patience to read/watch all his stuff. He does discuss the "bay of Piglets" as some kind of analogy.